# JAXB change the Element "name" of @XMLElements annotation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The root of my problem is a given XML with variable node names. 
The XML is already in use and can not be changed.

I created a XSD for the XML to generate the corrosponding Classes and then parse it through a DOMParser.

I use the DOMParser because through JAXB it is not parsable because of the variable tag-names but the generated classes are helpfull.

Now i just need an identifier for the variable Nodes in the Classes. I figured it would be best to just change the @XmlElement Annotations element "name" and give it a value like "?" to identifie the variable nodes, but i have no idea if and how it may be possible to change it.

I have already created an episode file to change some classnames and thought it could be changed through that but i didn't find a solution for this.

Example XML:

```
 <Settings>
    <Window>
        <Position Top="5" Left="5"/>
    </Window>
    <OpenData>
        <variable>
            <TableData>
                <variable-column00 POS="1" Visible="true" SortDesc="true"/>
                <variable-column01 POS="3" Visible="true" SortDesc="true"/>
                <variable-column02 POS="2" Visible="true" SortDesc="true"/>
            </TableData>
        </variable>
        <variable>
            <UserSettings>
                <variable-series1 Color="blue" Caption="Series blue" Visible="true" />
                <variable-series2 Color="yellow" Caption="Series yellow" Visible="true" />
                <variable-series3 Color="red" Caption="Series red" Visible="true" />
            </UserSettings>
            <ChartConfig>configuration-json....</ChartConfig>
        </variable>
        <variable/>
    </OpenData>
  </Settings>
```

The Variable Nodes would be: 
Nodes with the name "variable", Nodes beginning with "variable-column" and a number (sub-nodes of table-data) and the nodes beginning with "variable-series" and a number (sub-nodes of user-settings)

The XSD for this would be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:complexType name="Window">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Position" type="Position" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Position">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:attribute name="Top" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:attribute name="Left" type="xs:int" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OpenData">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- this would be the "variable" Node -->
            <xs:element name="View" type="View" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="View">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:sequence>
        <!-- normaly the order would be random, but because i use the DOMParser i don't need to pass that to JAXB -->
        <xs:element name="TableData" type="TableData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="UserSettings" type="UserSettings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="ChartConfig" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="UserSettings">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:sequence>
        <!-- the next Variable Node name beginning with "variable-series" and then a number -->
        <xs:element name="SeriesDefinition" type="SeriesDefinition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="SeriesDefinition">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:attribute name="Color" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="Caption" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="TableData">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:sequence>
        <!-- the next Variable Node name beginning with "variable-column" and then a number -->
        <xs:element name="Column" type="Column" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Column">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="SettingsElement">
        <xs:attribute name="POS" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:attribute name="Visible" type="xs:boolean" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="SettingsElement">
  </xs:element>


  <xs:element name="Settings" >
    <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Window" type="Window" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="OpenData" type="OpenData" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And after i generate it i the Class OpenData with List of View would be this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OpenData", propOrder = {
    "view"
})
public class OpenData extends SettingsElement implements Serializable {

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "View")
    protected java.util.List<View> view;

    public java.util.List<View> getview() {
        if (view == null) {
            view = new ArrayList<View>();
        }
        return this.view;
    }

}
```

I would need an identifier for my parsing to work and therefore something like changing the Annotation

```
@XmlElement(name = "View")
```

to

```
@XmlElement(name = "?")
```

So i know the Tag Name i am Searching for is not View but could be anything.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to change the generator.

First i readjust my pom like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-generator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>example</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
              <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
              <schemaIncludes>
                <include>configuration.xsd</include>
              </schemaIncludes>

              <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generateDirectory>
              <generatePackage>com.example.config</generatePackage>
              <extension>true</extension>
              <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
              </args>

              <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.1</version>
                </plugin>
              </plugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I used the org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.maven-jaxb2-plugin because it is easy to use with the jaxb2-basics-annotate plugin.
I gave the generationplugin a execution with an Id, a phase and goal, then in the configuration of the execution i showed it the path to the xsd file and named wich schema to use. Then i told it where to put the output and gave it one Argument, "-Xannotate" and that is the important part, with that and the given Plugin it is possible to Change annotations via a *.xjb File (Binding File)

i changed my *.episode file to an *.xjb File because the generator can auto detect them and added the lines to change the "XmlElement" Annotation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="Xequals annox" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.1">


  <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
  </jxb:globalBindings>

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="configuration.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Settings']">
      <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='OpenData']">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='View']">
          <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name="?")</annox:annotate>
          <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='TableData']">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Column']">
              <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name="?")</annox:annotate>
            </jxb:bindings>
          </jxb:bindings>
          <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='UserSettings']">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='SeriesDefinition']">
              <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name="?")</annox:annotate>
            </jxb:bindings>
          </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Now in the Generated Java Class e.g. UserSettings the XmlElement Annotation for the Variable SeriesDefinition is:

```
@XmlElement(name = "?")
```

And with Reflection i can get this Annotation and check if the "name" Propertie is "?" and write that in a Name Value i can Give the class.
Off course this only works if there is at max one Variable with the Annotation XmlElement(name = "?") in every class, i have to get every other Tag that has a defined name first and the rest has to be the ones with variable names.